# Python Pandas print() and .to_csv() truncating results

Tags: python, pandas, csv, printing

I have a dataframe with 8 columns and 1399 rows. When I use the print() function to display the dataframe, it comes out roughly like this:

```
        Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4    \
1       data        data        data        data
2       data        data        data        data
3       data        data        data        data
4       data        data        data        data
5       data        data        data        data
...     ...         ...         ....        ....
1395    data        data        data        data
1396    data        data        data        data
1397    data        data        data        data
1398    data        data        data        data
1399    data        data        data        data

    Column 5    Column 6    Column 7    Column 8
1       data        data        data        data
2       data        data        data        data
3       data        data        data        data
4       data        data        data        data
5       data        data        data        data
...     ...         ...         ....        ....
1395    data        data        data        data
1396    data        data        data        data
1397    data        data        data        data
1398    data        data        data        data
1399    data        data        data        data
```

I thought that this was just python making it easy to read via standard output, but when I use the .to_csv() function, the resulting .csv file looks exactly like the above. I've never had Pandas do this before. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the display.max_colwidth option to -1 as follows

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

for more detail check out [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)